# Why are all faces visible in non-wireframe edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, orthographic

This is probably a stupid question but it's making me go crazy.
I have an object and in object mode, it looks normal.

[image]

But when I go to edit mode (orthographic), I can see all faces even if I'm not using the wireframe viewport.

[image]

It seems to be fine in perspective however.

[image]

It has no modifiers whatsoever and it's never happened before. Thanks for help in advance

Comment: You have X-Ray mode on.  2.79 is pretty old and I don't remember how to update the setting, but there's a setting for disabling it.  In newer versions of Blender it's in the header.

Comment: @MartyFouts I found the x-ray in the properties panel > object > display, but it's not checked either

Comment: Hello! maybe try Alt + Z to disable it?

Comment: If it's only working in edit mode, it doesn't seems to be X Ray, the only thing that could cause that (as far as i know) could be "Limit selection to vibisible" (the white square on the right of face selection icon) but it looks like it's off... Try a factory reset.

Comment: Did you try flip the normals?

Comment: @AyoReis Alt Z just turns the viewport into texture mode for me

Comment: @Emir It's really weird, I have another 2.79 file that works just fine, it seems like this particular file is giving me trouble

Comment: @FFeller I flipped the normals and it looks like how you would expect flipped normals to look like but it still has the internal outline

Comment: @AHundredHoursLater I never used 2.79. But on newer versions it show a wireframe just like on your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of attempts it seems like the file itself was corrupt in some way because not only did I just find out my other object in the scene disappeared (bottom part of a butter dish lol) but also the problem was immediately solved after I started a new file and pasted my object into it. Weird.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it's an older version i.e 2.79.
Look I think you've switched to the toggle mode (Alt+Z)
[image: Toggle XRay mode]

Comment: I think the equivalent in 2.79 is limit selection to visible, which makes no difference whether I click it or not.